# I need to add an if else statement to discern wether or not an image was uploaded to a Flask application

Tags: python, html, flask

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, render_template,request,jsonify,url_for
from transformers import ViTImageProcessor, ViTForImageClassification
from ultralytics import YOLO
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('homepage.html')

@app.route('/VIT_model', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def VIT():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if None in ['photo']:
            return render_template('VIT_model.html', error="No file uploaded")
              
        img = request.files['photo']
        image = Image.open(img)
        
        feature_extractor = ViTImageProcessor.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224')
        model = ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224')
        inputs = feature_extractor(images=image, return_tensors="pt")
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.logits

        predicted_class_idx = logits.argmax(-1).item()
        prediction = model.config.id2label[predicted_class_idx]
        
        return render_template('VIT_prediction.html', prediction=prediction)
    
    return render_template('VIT_model.html')
```

Here is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/VIT_model.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>VIT Model</h1>
    <br>
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
    <br>
    <form action="/VIT_model" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="photo">Select a photo:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" accept="image/*">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form method="get" action="/">
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'homepage.html';">Home</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried checking the file uploaded but it still seems to give me problems, I want it to return the error message, I also need to implement an if statement that will check the file type and return an error if the file type is incorrect, the working files are .png .jpg .jpeg

Comment: your route captures GET and POST methods, but the code only processes POST methods. Add an `elif request.method == 'GET':` to implement the GET method.

Comment: Hope help to you https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/